# Is there a .Net technology equivalent to scriptable Java applets? (for a specific use-case)

Tags: java, javascript, .net, silverlight, applet

One of the core technology components at my company is a Java Applet for digital signature. This is a headless component, in the sense that all presentation is handled via HTML/CSS, and the applet methods are invoked from Javascript. The applet itself is not visible in the page.

Now we've come to a situation where we have some specific signature format (signature embedded in docx [OfficeOpenXML] documents) that is more easily handled using .Net classes, and we have some prototype implementation as a .Net DLL.

In the olden COM years, Active/X components were used in web pages with a similar purpose, and were scriptable too. I would like to know what (if any) is the equivalent now for embedding .Net classes and scripting them using Javascript.

What is the technology to use? Would Silverlight be the approach, or is it biased towards RIA, i.e. apps with a visual appearance? If it is a good solution, I will greatly appreciate pointers to tutorials or code samples in that direction. I've had roughly 1 year exposure to .Net (C#) in the past but none to Silverlight.

Comment: Are you looking to do this on the client (web browser) side?

Comment: SilverLight I think? Wait, if you tagged it, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The problem with Silverlight is that if he wants to modify Word documents on the local computer, he's going to have problems.  Trying to modify files on the local machine from a web browser is an incredibly bad thing to do, hence many of these "technologies" that he referred to (ActiveX, Applets) have gone away.

Comment: At least in the niche of digital signature, applets are far from gone, since they offer the only interoperable solution. But in our case they are "hiding behind the screen" and not participating in visualisation. Yes, it has to be a client-side technology (in order to access the user's certificates in the local computer). Files themselves will be in the server, signed and posted back. We'll try to minimise traffic as we do with applets (we pre-process and post-process docs in the server and only move around hashes and signatures)

Comment: He can use Silverlight out of the browser to modify local files, but that's not what it sounds like. He wants a .Net equivalent to Java applets, and since applets are sandboxed, presumably he's not looking for a solution that won't work in a sandbox.

Comment: Yup, is there a security model similar to Java, where e.g. signed applets can be "trusted" and run in a less restricted environment ("out of the sandbox")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is **not** the technology to use here.  It doesn't offer you the access to the user's system that you require.

However there is nothing stopping you from creating an ActiveX/COM component using .NET code.  You can then create COM/Scriptable friendly wrapper around the the full .NET classes you need to do your work.

Of course this ceases to be cross-browser.  If you need a cross-browser solution then you are into a world of pain since you will need to interface from extension tech for other browsers into some .NET code.  This may well involve some COM along way.

Comment: Cross-browser is not really a requirement in this case. Scripting with Javascript/jQuery is. Can you provide some pointers to how to write these COM wrappers around .Net code?

Comment: @Carles: Read through this section in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Doing a more guided search following your suggestions, I found this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_com_obj_for_javascript.aspx "C# COM Object for Use In JavaScript / HTML, Including Event Handling" that seems to wrap it all up.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Silverlight is .Net equivalent to Java applets. You write your code in C#, VB, Python, Ruby, etc. and you can interact with it via the DOM and Javascript.

In one of your comments, though, you indicate that you want to sign documents with client certificates stored on the local machine. I don't know of any way to do that with a browser-based Silverlight app. You can use an out-of-browser Silverlight app to load a COM object to do your bidding for you, but then you wouldn't be able to script it.

Comment: Getting hold of the users certificates on their local computer isn't possible from a Silverlight plugin.

Comment: Anthony: You might be right. He can probably do it in an OOB app, but then he wouldn't be able to script it.

Comment: Could you point me to some objective info about restrictions that apply to Silverlight components, i.e. in terms of parts of the .Net API/libraries that are not accessible due to security/runtime limitations?

Comment: I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194%28v=VS.95%29.aspx and there is no support for System.IO.Packaging, which includes the classes to support digital signature for OpenXML docs... out of luck here

Comment: Doing some reading around in MSDN it looks to me like Silverlight is focused on building RIAs and competing with Flash and doesn't look like an appropriate solution for this case. Prove me wrong.